# Meta-model descriptor identifier "org.artop.aal.autosar40" is not unique

Tags: eclipse-plugin, rcp, autosar

Recently I have updated my target platform with ARTOP SDK 4.14.1 and I am facing the below issue while running my eclipse RCP product. Can anyone help me here?

!MESSAGE Meta-model descriptor identifier "org.artop.aal.autosar40" is not unique.
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Meta-model descriptor identifier "org.artop.aal.autosar40" is not unique.
at org.eclipse.sphinx.emf.metamodel.MetaModelDescriptorRegistry.addDescriptor(MetaModelDescriptorRegistry.java:283)
at org.eclipse.sphinx.emf.metamodel.MetaModelDescriptorRegistry.readContributedDescriptors(MetaModelDescriptorRegistry.java:221)
at org.eclipse.sphinx.emf.metamodel.MetaModelDescriptorRegistry.lazyInitialization(MetaModelDescriptorRegistry.java:1327)
at org.eclipse.sphinx.emf.metamodel.MetaModelDescriptorRegistry.getMetaModelDescriptors(MetaModelDescriptorRegistry.java:1334)
at org.eclipse.sphinx.emf.metamodel.MetaModelDescriptorRegistry.getDescriptors(MetaModelDescriptorRegistry.java:526)
at org.eclipse.sphinx.emf.scoping.ResourceScopeProviderRegistry.getMetaModelDescriptors(ResourceScopeProviderRegistry.java:185)
at org.eclipse.sphinx.emf.scoping.ResourceScopeProviderRegistry.addResourceScopeProvider(ResourceScopeProviderRegistry.java:155)
at org.eclipse.sphinx.emf.scoping.ResourceScopeProviderRegistry.readContributedResourceScopeProviders(ResourceScopeProviderRegistry.java:106)
at org.eclipse.sphinx.emf.scoping.ResourceScopeProviderRegistry.readContributedResourceScopeProviders(ResourceScopeProviderRegistry.java:79)
at org.eclipse.sphinx.emf.scoping.ResourceScopeProviderRegistry.(ResourceScopeProviderRegistry.java:63)
at org.eclipse.sphinx.emf.scoping.ResourceScopeProviderRegistry.(ResourceScopeProviderRegistry.java:43)
at org.eclipse.sphinx.emf.model.ModelDescriptorRegistry.addModel(ModelDescriptorRegistry.java:96)
at org.eclipse.sphinx.emf.internal.model.ModelDescriptorRegistryInitializer.run(ModelDescriptorRegistryInitializer.java:82)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)